# row,column detection in OpenCV (OCR preprocessing)

Tags: image-processing, opencv, image-segmentation

first my final goal is to process the following image with tesseract:
http://ubuntuone.com/72m0ujsL9RhgfMIlugRDWP
(I wiped out the second and the third column...)

However tesseract has problems with the dotted background. So my idea is to pre-process the image with OpenCV. The best would be if I could somehow detect each line, because I need to remove the dotted background by applying a different threshold than to even lines. Is there any solution to solve my problem? So far I have found Hough Transformation and maybe segmentation, but the results weren't very good (maybe because of wrong parameter)... But I'm not sure, if these are possible approaches and what I invest my time best on. 
Column detection would be fine, too, because the second column contains numbers and the third characters, only. Passing this "knowledge" to tesseract could improve its detection rate even more.

I would be really thankful if somebody could give me some hints how to solve this issue and which OpenCV functions are used best, with which paremeters. Some snippets that give me a fair idea about the different steps would be helpful, too.

Thank in advance!!!

Kind regards.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? If so please share as i also have a similar issue. Also the image link is no longer available. Could you update that too? Thansk

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use something like erosion, as the dots seem to be rather small as compared to the width of the letters.

OR I would Canny edge detection with proper thresholds so that I would discard the rather short and thin edges of the dots.

Hope this helps, have fun!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I already tried erosion, however this kind of "destroyed" the characters and so the ocr. As already said I would prefer an approach segmenting (line+row=>cell) the image properly, because this would help to define the expected content for tesseract.